# Why are my cross-validation scores unrealistically high?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation, scikit-learn

I am working on a two-class classification task that involves the classification of samples from 10 subjects who belong to two different classes. The three main variables are:

- X - feature matrix (1650 x 30).
- y - target array (1650,)
- groups -
  array holding the participant id corresponding to each sample (1650,)

My classification pipeline consists of three steps: standardization, feature selection and SVM classification. I have applied grid search cross-validation to find the best hyperparameters and perform cross-validation simultaneously. I have selected leave-one-group-out (LOGO-CV) as cross-validation scheme because the feature matrix contains ordered data from the participants.

```
# Pipeline
pipe = Pipeline([('sca', StandardScaler()),
                 ('sel', SelectKBest(f_classif)),                      
                 ('clf', SVC(kernel = 'rbf', random_state = 100))])            

# Parameter grid
param_grid = [{'clf__C'         : [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
               'clf__gamma'     : [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001],
               'sel__k'         : [10, 20]}]

# Grid-search cross validation
cv     = LeaveOneGroupOut()
search = GridSearchCV(estimator          = pipe,
                      param_grid         = param_grid,
                      scoring            = 'f1_weighted',
                      return_train_score = True, 
                      cv                 = cv).fit(X, y, groups = groups)
```

The following figure displays the cross-validation scheme (left) and the test and training scores per fold (subject) obtained during cross-validation for the best set of hyperparameters (right).
[image]

I am very skeptical about the results. First, I noticed the training score was 100% on every fold, so I thought the model was overfitting.
Then, I checked the test score and realized it was very high (91% average across folds).

As I understand, perfect training score and very high test score occur when a model is trained and evaluated on very similar data, however, in this case I am applying LOGO-CV, so there should not exist a subject bias.

Can someone explain this (in my opinion) unrealistic performance?

Comment: Any other reason to believe it's wrong? Maybe your classifier is just doing good? Have you tried using a completely different model (e.g. logistic regression, or decision tree) as a comparison? You could also try using a standard hold-out test set as a comparison. Maybe the groups are very similar to each other, so train & test distributions are identical?

Comment: Hey @Tim, regarding your comments:
1. Yes, I have compared the results of the SVC with other classifiers (logistic regression and decision tree) and the results yielded by these classifiers are similar compared to the ones I reported in the OP.
2. Yes, I have tried extracting a subset of the dataset before carrying out grid search  to perform a sanity check after cross-validation, and the score in this subset is similar (or even better) to the average test score yielded during cross-validation. 3. I have no other reason to believe it's wrong, just my intuition.

Comment: One other thing to check for is a feature that leaks some of the target.  That'll be easier with the logistic regression model, where you can analyze the (selected features') coefficients to see what the model finds most important.  But otherwise, I'm with @Tim that it may just be an easier problem than you expected.

Comment: Hey @BenReiniger, I think it is unlikely that a feature is leaking some of the target because features are EEG power spectral densities and the target indicates disease cohort (unless I am missing something). I will go through the code again to be sure and I will also check logistic regression coefficients.